# CPQ QuoteLine Editor page got attempt to de-reference null object error when we introduce recordType.name in the formula

Tags: cpq, quotelineitem

In Salesforce CPQ, in quote, when we have a formula like below:

```
IF(Contains(SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.RecordType.Name, "Agent"), "Agent", "")
```

The QuoteLine Editor will throw attempt to de-reference a null object error when we try to save the QuoteLine.

The formula actually works by itself but it actually breaks the QuoteLine Editor.

Since QuoteLine Editor page is a VF page in the CPQ managed package, I can't find anything useful in the debug log. When I change the formula back to use hard-coded RecordTypeId the issue just gone.

Can I know why this could be an issue for CPQ QuoteLine Editor?

**Edit**
Following the comment, I paste the result of my browser's error info here: 
[image]

It does provide some information here. But based on this, I still haven't got a clue about what exactly is happening. Any ideas about that?

Comment: Salesforce CPQ errors often shed more light through browsers developer console. Did you try checking that?

Comment: @ShaileshPatil Thank you for your information. I have just done that. It does provide a bit information there but I still haven't got any clue about what was happening. I paste the screenshot of that edited in my answer.

Comment: It seems internally the CPQ is calling your formula field for something. May be you try using RecordType.DeveloperName instead of RecordType.Name. Not sure if this solve your problem.

Comment: Did you add that field to the referenced fields fieldset on the Quote?